# Is there any tool to help convert ActiveBatch jobs to PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, activebatch

I can export the Jobs to xml files so i was looking for a software that can covert or help me convert this jobs to PowerShell or at least be able to read the Jobs in a more easy way and undestand each step. I have not been able to find anything yet.

Thanks!

Ive tried exporting them to XML but there is not much i can do with that xml, just load it up again in ActiveBatch.

Comment: Isn't ActiveBatch a scheduling platform for automated workflows? What makes you think there's a 1-to-1 mapping between actions on said platform and PowerShell commands?